# PrestaShop: Can't access newly added resource through webservice

Tags: php, web-services, module, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have created users table in Prestashop database in phpMyAdmin, the schema of that table is :

```
CREATE TABLE users (
 id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 Token int NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (id),
 UNIQUE KEY (Token)
);
```

I want to add this table in my webservice resource list as like other resources and access that resource from another application.

To do this I have done so far the following tasks:

1. I have created `/prestashop/mymodule/override/classes/webservice/ WebserviceRequest.php`:

   ```
   class WebserviceRequest extends WebserviceRequestCore {
       public static function getResources(){
           $resources = parent::getResources();
           $resources['users'] = array('description' => 'Device registration', 'class' => 'Users');
           ksort($resources);
           return $resources;
       }
   }
   ```
2. and `/prestashop/mymodule/override/classes/Users.php`:

   ```
   class Users extends ObjectModel {
       public static $definition = array(
           'table' => 'users',
           'primary' => 'id',
           'fields' => array(
               'Token' => array('type' => self::TYPE_INT)
           )
        );
       protected $webserviceParameters = array();
    }
   ```

As a result I found the table in webservice resource list. But when I hit the URL: `example.com/api/users` no XML data is returned.

I have googled a lot for the problem but didn't find any effective solution for: How to add a new database table `users` in webservice resources and access the resource using `example.com/api/users` URL.

Comment: Are you sure? Just tested and it works. Which XML data do you want? Have you multishop activated'

Comment: See yourself from [here](http://ps1615.tanzows.it/api/).
API key: ZFWQ5LFUIAEKHHUPRC5QIZPRSRW34B7N

:)

Comment: Yes, I did the above steps.No, I did not activated multishop. am I missing something ?

Comment: how did you do this ? please tell me steps to achieve your output

Comment: Have you add the prefix to the table name? In my case `ps_` (ps_users)

Comment: No, I am adding the prefix and checking

Comment: Should I add the prefix in code base also ?

Comment: No, only the table name must have the prefix

Comment: Still no output. Is my code right brother ?

Comment: Your code is right, I used your code to show you the example. Check if you used `ps_` like a prefix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All correct but, only small corrections:

table must have the prefix choosed during installation (default is `ps_`) :

```
CREATE TABLE ps_users (
 id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 Token int NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (id),
 UNIQUE KEY (Token)
);
```

Point 1 is ok ;)

Point 2, don't forget to add the table field(s) as public var otherwise the XML will not show the informations stored in the db:

```
class UsersAPI extends ObjectModel {
    public $Token;

    public static $definition = array(
        'table' => 'users',
        'primary' => 'id',
        'fields' => array(
            'Token' => array('type' => self::TYPE_INT)
        )
    );
    protected $webserviceParameters = array();
}
```

**EDIT:**
If you have made an override don't forget to delete the `prestashop/cache/class_index.php`.

Comment: My friend, I send the files, but it's the same of your posted code :). Have you already deleted the file `class_index.php` in `prestashop/cache/`? Have you checked if the file `UsersAPI.php` is in the folder?

Comment: Hi sarcom , how the xlinks are formed ? I am getting http://example1.com/api/tokenss/1  for tokens resource. that should be http://example1.com/api/tokens/1